# Sound-Lost sound somehow

Tags: sound, settings, preferences

I have lost sound in Ubuntu 18.04. I have checked the other questions regarding sound but none of them seem to fit my situation.  I have gone through the troubleshooting steps in Help but I can't find any settings that are wrong.

Where do I go in the menus or the directory structure to check for editable sound properties?

Suggestions please.

Comment: I found the sound settings under Gnome Control Center/Sound and I was able to test my speakers; they tested true; but, when I go back to Spotify and try to play a song, I get no sound.  I also get no sound when I do different actions with my mouse or keyboard; I was getting different sound effects before when I performed certain actions with my keyboard or mouse.  Is it possible that I inadvertently pressed a key combination that turned off the sound?

Comment: I am able to play some sample .wav files in Rhythmbox application with success.  Also, when I go to Gnome Control Center/Sound/Applications/Spotify, there is  the red circle with the slash going through it which I understand is the universal symbol for stop, halt, or "don't go there" instead of the Spotify icon; could it be that Ubuntu is blocking Spotify from accessing the sound card?

Comment: I was able to get sound on Google Chrome and Firefox on YouTube for a while, but after about 30 minutes, Ubuntu shut the sound off of those applications as well. (???)

Comment: No idea, but you may also want to test using aplay which uses pulseaudio directly. Do you have any idea what changed from when it worked till when it stopped? Did you configure anything or install packages or updates? Where I often run into troubles (in KDE) is with sound profiles. If the default sound profile gets set to HDMI, then nothing comes out of my notebook speakers. With KDE: Settings->Hardware->Multimedia->Audio And Video->Audio Hardware Setup->Hardware->Sound Card and ...->Profile. Hopefully, it's somewhat similar under Gnome.